# Replace columns values by other values conditionally in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to remove the description in a data frame if the value is identical to the caption:

```
m[m.Description == m.Caption].Description = \
    m[m.Description == m.Caption].Description.map(lambda x: '')
```

I feel this writing is quite boilerplate:

```
df[condition][columns] = df[condition][columns].map(lambda x: value)
```

Is there a better syntax to do the same? I imagine something like:

```
df[condition][columns].map(lambda x: value, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I can't test it now but maybe this would work `m['Description'][m.Description == m.Caption] = ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m.loc[m.Description == m.Caption, 'Description'] = ' '
```

Sample:

```
m = pd.DataFrame({'Description':['a','b','f'],
                   'Caption':['a','c',''],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (m)
   C Caption Description
0  7       a           a
1  8       c           b
2  9                   f

m.loc[m.Description == m.Caption, 'Description'] = ' '
print (m)
   C Caption Description
0  7       a            
1  8       c           b
2  9                   f
```

Alternatively use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
m['Description'] = m['Description'].mask(m.Description == m.Caption, ' ')
print (m)
   C Caption Description
0  7       a            
1  8       c           b
2  9                   f
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or use `mask`